# How to get the array of object property value.?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array of object i need only those object which property has some value more than 0 on the given slot_time how would I get the output like this.

```
var array = [
  { time: "10:30", slot: 3, product_Id: 77, amount: 30 }
  , { time: "11:00", slot: 4, product_Id: 77, amount: 30 }
  , { time: "11:30", slot: 2, product_Id: 77, amount: 30 }
  , { time: "12:00", slot: 0, product_Id: 77, amount: 30 }
  , { time: "12:30", slot: 0, product_Id: 77, amount: 30 }
]
```

output:

```
booking_items: [{
        "product_id": "",
        "slot_time": " "
        "slot_quantity": "",
        "amount": "",
        "sub_amount": ""
    },
    {
        "product_id": "",
        "slot_time": ""
        "slot_quantity": "",
        "amount": "",
        "sub_amount": ""
    }
]
```

Comment: give some sample time and corresponding output. so we can try based on that

Comment: hi @sarvonks can we return another object based on a n condition if slot !==0 then return another object.

Comment: Why are all properties empty strings in the output? Please create a [mcve] with what you've tried so far?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We can use `filter()`:

```js
var array = [
{ time: "10:30", slot: 3, product_Id: 77, amount : 30},
{ time: "11:00", slot: 4, product_Id: 77, amount : 30 },
{ time: "11:30", slot: 2, product_Id: 77, amount : 30 },
{ time: "12:00", slot: 0, product_Id: 77, amount: 30 },
{ time: "12:30", slot: 0, product_Id: 77, amount: 30 }
]

var booking_items = array.filter(obj => obj.slot > 0)
console.log(booking_items)
```

The code makes the check `obj.slot > 0` for each object in the array and returns an array with all the objects that passed the check.

Comment: Hi thank you, How would i get the slot value in each time.?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, can you clarify what you want to happen and your desired output?

Comment: I need slot property value by comparing its 1st property that is time.

Comment: What comparison would be made? Sorry, I'm still unsure of what you want to achieve.

Comment: for checking which time these slot has been booked. Like someone booked 3 slots at 10:30 then we are storing it in slot_quantity. I am attaching the sandbox here. Thank you for you help. https://codesandbox.io/s/2v15vl8rk0

Comment: So you want to enter a time, and then get how many slots are booked for that time?

Comment: I just wanna check how many slots are there in each time.

Comment: You can just loop over the array and utilise the value there: `booking_items.forEach(item => console.log(item.slot))`. You might want to use a different data structure, if you want to get information based on the time.